# jquery - calling function from inside function

Tags: jquery

I got the following code:

```
function open_viewer() {
  $('.image_thumb').click(function(){
    var reqz = 'id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&i='+$(this).attr('i');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_images',
      data: reqz,
      success: function (data) {
        $('#viewer').remove();
        $('body').prepend(data);
        $('#viewer_close').click(function() {
          $('#viewer').remove();
        });
        $('.viewer_button').click(function() {
          var reqz = 'id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&i='+$(this).attr('i');
          $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_images',
            data: reqz,
            success: function (data) {
              $('#viewer').remove();
              $('body').prepend(data);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I am trying to call the $.ajax() every time I press .viewer_button and as the result I changed the code to the following:

```
function open_viewer() {
    var reqz = 'id='+$(this).attr('id')+'&i='+$(this).attr('i');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_images',
      data: reqz,
      success: function (data) {
        $('#viewer').remove();
        $('body').prepend(data);
        $('#viewer_close').click(function() {
          $('#viewer').remove();
        });
        $('.viewer_button').click(function() {
                      open_viewer();
        });
      }
    });
}
```

But that calls an infinite loop and does not work. Maybe someone could point me into the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting the call to the click functions outside of the open_viewer() function

Comment: Forgot to mention. Class .viewer_button comes up only after you press .image_thumb and $.ajax returns it. If I  put the call to the click functions outside of the open_viewer() function, .viewer_button will not be there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [delegation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of defining handlers in the ajax success callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent").on("click", ".viewer_button", function(e) {
        ...
    });

});
```

For `#parent` you choose a selector for a static parent element closest to `.viewer_button`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use functions?

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.image_thumb').click(function(){

   });

    $('.viewer_button').click(function() {


    });
});
```

The inside code will be executed  for each click.

Comment: You can use and `.on('click',function(){ });` instead  `.click()`

Comment: Forgot to mention. Class .viewer_button comes up only after you press .image_thumb and $.ajax returns it. If I use your answer, .viewer_button will not be there yet.

Comment: Okey , you can use your style `$('.image_thumb').click(function(){
... success: function (data) { 
$('.viewer_button').click(function() {
    });
}
...
   });`

Comment: Yeah, but: 1. I am trying to minimize the code; 2. After clicking .viewer_button, I may click .viewer_button again. In that case I'll have to use $('.image_thumb').click(function(){ ... success: function (data) {  $('.viewer_button').click(function() {  $('.viewer_button').click(function() {     });   }); } ...    });  What if I have to click it 60 times?

Comment: I cannot understand why You try to restrict by this way. Can you post more code (html)? You can change classname dynamical for on/off ajax request. (If You remove class .viewer_button will prevent clicks).